# Meaning of "productivity hacker's wet dream"

Tags: meaning

In the following sentence, I don't understand the meaning of the second part (*productivity hacker's wet dream*):

> Depending on your perspective, the philosopher Immanuel Kant was either the most boring person who ever lived or **a productivity hacker's wet dream.**  For over 40 years, he woke up every morning at 5:00 AM and wrote for exactly three hours. [...] From [blog article](https://markmanson.net/the-one-rule-for-life)

Thank you.

Comment: Standard definitions are used, what confuses you?

Answer (score 5):

So I'm not going to go into terrible detail with this, for reasons which will become obvious when you read the link.

Essentially, a wet dream is a way to say a very **very** good dream. [Read more on in this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnal_emission). When you describe something as your wet dream, it means the activity, person, object is very exciting.

The author is just saying that Kant is either very boring or really interesting, depending on your perspective. More likely the latter if you are a productivity hacker. I.e. someone who enjoys to learn new tricks and tips about how to be productive.

Comment: This is a good example of a phrase which is considered *vulgar* but not *profane*, as none of the words are themselves swearwords.  It's an expression many would regard as completely out of place at work, not least of which for sexism.  In passing, I can't see how people interested in productivity would be especially interested in Kant's work.

Comment: @jonathanjo I don't actually know who he is I was just explaining what a "productivity hacker" would mean to me

Comment: your explanation seems perfect, and I understand "productivity hacker" the same way.  Just commenting what a strange thought of the original!

Comment: @jonathanjo having looked up where the original quote is from: [Article](https://markmanson.net/the-one-rule-for-life) It looks like the author actually means that Kant was a very productive person who you might (as a productivity hacker) admire.

Comment: @Bee - It's okay to tell folks what to do when they like an answer, but it's also best to remind them to [wait about a day to do so](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: @J.R.Since they said thank you and mentioned it was what they were looking for and they are new to the site I just wanted to let them them know how to if they are happy with it. There are a lot of answered questions on this site where answers haven't been accepted